# Raise real SQL Error from Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following stored procedure and I would like to return the actual SQL Server error occurred rather than my message, how can this be done?

I am currently using `RAISERROR` and displaying a message but I would like to return the actual SQL error.

Thanks

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_DBA_DROPFIELD] 
(
    @fieldDisplayName varchar(max),
    @tableSeq int,
    @viewName varchar(max),
    @isVirtual varchar(4)
)
AS
  DECLARE   
    @sql_table_name varchar(max),
    @sql_fieldname varchar(max),
    @sql_columnName varchar(max),
    @sql_fieldSeq int,
    @sql_SEQ_FKTABLE int,
    @sql_FKTABLENAME varchar(max),
    @sql_EXEC_DROPCONSTRAINT varchar(max),
    @sql_EXEC_DROPCOLUMN varchar(max),
    @sql_EXEC_DELETEVIRTUAL varchar(max),
    @sql_EXEC_DELETEFIELDREF int
BEGIN TRAN
BEGIN TRY
select @sql_table_name = TABLENAME from SD_TABLES where SEQUENCE = + @tableSeq
select @sql_columnName = COLUMN_NAME, @sql_fieldSeq = SEQUENCE, @sql_SEQ_FKTABLE = FK_TABLE from SD_FIELDS where DISPLAY_NAME = @fieldDisplayName AND SEQ_TABLE = @tableSeq

if @sql_SEQ_FKTABLE IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
Select @sql_FKTABLENAME = TABLENAME from SD_TABLES where SEQUENCE = @sql_SEQ_FKTABLE
SET @sql_EXEC_DROPCONSTRAINT = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @sql_table_name + ' DROP CONSTRAINT [FK__' + @sql_table_name + '___' + @sql_FKTABLENAME + '_]'
SET @sql_EXEC_DROPCOLUMN = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @sql_table_name + ' DROP COLUMN ' +  @sql_columnName
EXEC sp_executesql @sql_EXEC_DROPCONSTRAINT
EXEC sp_executesql @sql_EXEC_DROPCOLUMN
END

if @isVirtual = 'true'
BEGIN
SET @sql_EXEC_DELETEVIRTUAL = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @sql_table_name + ' DROP COLUMN ' + @sql_columnName
EXEC sp_executesql @sql_EXEC_DELETEVIRTUAL 
END

SET @sql_EXEC_DELETEFIELDREF = 'DELETE FROM SD_FIELDS WHERE SEQUENCE = ' + @sql_fieldSeq
EXEC sp_executesql @sql_EXEC_DELETEFIELDREF

COMMIT 

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN
   RAISERROR('An error has occured, no changes have been made', 5, 1)
END CATCH
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: thank you marc, yes I remember that now. I will change it. Did you actually answer my question as I can't seem to see it in the edits. Thanks

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server are you using? The 2012 version has new functionality that would make this easier....

Comment: you can use `ERROR_MESSAGE()` function inside `TRY-CATCH`. check this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976(v=sql.90).aspx)

Comment: You should consider asking your question on [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to create this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RethrowError]
AS
-- Return if there is no error information to retrieve.
IF ERROR_NUMBER() IS NULL
    RETURN;

DECLARE 
    @ErrorMessage    NVARCHAR(4000),
    @ErrorNumber     INT,
    @ErrorSeverity   INT,
    @ErrorState      INT,
    @ErrorLine       INT,
    @ErrorProcedure  NVARCHAR(200);

-- Assign variables to error-handling functions that 
-- capture information for RAISERROR.
SELECT 
    @ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER(),
    @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
    @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(),
    @ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE(),
    @ErrorProcedure = ISNULL(ERROR_PROCEDURE(), '-');

-- Build the message string that will contain original
-- error information.
SELECT @ErrorMessage = 
    N'Error %d, Level %d, State %d, Procedure %s, Line %d, ' + 
        'Message: '+ ERROR_MESSAGE();

-- Raise an error: msg_str parameter of RAISERROR will contain
-- the original error information.
RAISERROR 
    (
    @ErrorMessage, 
    @ErrorSeverity, 
    1,               
    @ErrorNumber,    -- parameter: original error number.
    @ErrorSeverity,  -- parameter: original error severity.
    @ErrorState,     -- parameter: original error state.
    @ErrorProcedure, -- parameter: original error procedure name.
    @ErrorLine       -- parameter: original error line number.
    );
```

And then use it like this:

```
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRAN
    EXEC dbo.RethrowError
END CATCH
```